# Generating a dynamic nested JSON objects inside an array - python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a script through which I am scraping data from multiple pages. I am trying to generate dynamic nested JSON objects inside an array. But the **result I am getting is that there are nested JSON objects but inside two lists**. The output data starts like this **['"[{** and ends ****}]"']**** like this. I need someone who can explain to me where I am making a mistake?

**** I am pasting my code below please have a look ****

I am pasting below my code.

```py
def geturl():
    urls = [
    
        # list of URLs
    ]
    
    with open('temp.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for url in urls:
            r = requests.get(url)
            print(r.status_code)
            data = json.loads(r.content)
            items = data['items']
            baseurl =  # URL
            data = OrderedDict()
            main = []
            for item in items:
                data['Title'] = item['name']
                data["Price"] = item['price']
                data['Detai Page'] = baseurl + item['slug']
                data['Image'] = item['thumb_image']
    
                main.append(data)
                result = json.dumps(main)
        json.dump(result, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

geturl()
```

**Someone, please help me how to solve this issue?**

Comment: " data= r.json() " works?

Comment: No. Data coming in perfecting but I am having issues while writing it in a file.

Comment: Run script for one url and print(main), does it store data correctly? Also code indentation is not proper in question.

Comment: Yes, with the first URL it does store data correctly.

Comment: The indentation of your code is probably wrong. If it really is like that on your side, then look into that problem first. Otherwise, please make sure the indentation is just like you have it on your side.

Comment: Indentations are fine. It's working fine on my side. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Provide the `URL` for which you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work file

```
import pandas as pd
def geturl(filehandler):
  urls =[ # your urls here ] 

  main = []  
  baseurl = # your base url

  for url in urls:
  
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.content)
    items = data['items']     
    
    for item in items:
      data = {}
      data['Title'] = item['name']
      data["Price"] = item['price']
      data['Detai Page'] = baseurl+item['slug']
      data['Image'] = item['thumb_image']
      main.append(data)
    
  # writing to json file
  json.dump(main, filehandler)

  # reading with pandas
  df= pd.DataFrame(main)
  df.to_json('data.json', orient='records')

  

with open('temp.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as filehandler:
  geturl(filehandler)
```